# How to make a column based auto_incrementer in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Basically I want to make a column auto_increment based on another column's value.  For instance I have column A and column B.  Column A is an int 1-100 and column b is the auto_incrementer.  If I do something with Column A = 2 column b's incrementer value needs to increase by 1.  Let's say its 5 now.  Now I change something with Column A = 8 and B changes from 11 to 12.  My question is how can I implement something like this without creating a lot of tables?  Or is creating a lot of tables the most efficient method?

Comment: you need trigger for something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a trigger, which updates column B based on the value in column A. The trigger function will handle all computations required for the value of column B